# spring security implementation to secure REST APIs in my spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, spring-security-rest

I have a RestController which has one API that is used to authenticate a user. I want this API to be accessible by anyone whether authenticated or not and irrespective of their roles. In other words, this API should be called when someone types in their username and password and presses submit button.

Here is the config(HttpSecurity http) method of security config java file

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http/* .csrf().disable() */
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
            .antMatchers("/supplier/**").hasRole("SUPPLIER")
            .antMatchers("/user/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
      }
```

In the above code, I've written ''antMatchers("/user/authenticate").permitAll()'' because I want this url to be accessible by everyone and whatever logic is written in the controller should be executed.

And here is my controller

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public void authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) {
    Authentication token = authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
    // more code
   }
}
```

But I don't know why it is not working. When I send a POST request from POSTMAN, I get the following response back:

```
    {
       "timestamp": "2020-07-24T08:50:02.514+00:00",
       "status": 403,
       "error": "Forbidden",
       "message": "Forbidden",
       "path": "/user/authenticate"
    }
```

Someone please suggest what I should do to make it hit my REST controller

Comment: It is a post request and csrf is not disabled

Comment: Thank you @KavithakaranKanapathippillai, I am able to hit my controller now. Could you please tell what POST request has to do with CRSF?

Comment: If the csrf is not disabled, for `POST`, `PUT`, DELETE` requests , spring security expects  you will send a `csrf` token as well. When you do it in browser, first you do a get request and server responds with login page and also a `hidden` csrf token in the login page and when you submit, the hidden token is submitted and thats why you don't face the issue in the browser.  Do a `GET` request to the same endpoint in POSTMAN and check the response, it will a hidden csrf token